# Humanity+ logo in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, draw

I'm trying to do by scratch the Humanity+ logo, by using TikZ.  The best thing I can do is:

```
\newcommand\tikzhumanitypluslogo{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=(current bounding box.north)]
        \draw[thick] (-0.04,-0.25) -- (0,0) arc(-265:60:0.25);
        \draw (0.06,-0.25) node[]
            {\sf\smaller\emph{h}\textsuperscript{\smaller+}};
    \end{tikzpicture}}
```

But my result is: [image: TikZ version of H+ logo]

Close, but not close enough.  How can I get a more precise representation of the original logo in order to be inserted as another character in the paragraph?

Original logo: [image: Humanity+ Logo]

Thanks.

Comment: why redraw it? (you might also want to give a link to the original) Usually for logos it is best to simply include the original rather than try to fake it with a tex typeset version.

Comment: the logo at https://humanityplus.org/about/trademarks/  (if that is the same thing) uses a looped script h.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following attempt uses `ultra thick` lines for the circle, draws the *h* in sans serif italics boldface (with T1 encoding), draws the plus as two sans serif boldface minuses, because the minus in this font has rounded corners while the plus does not, a bit resized because the minus is larger than the plus, and a white line under the *h* because the character also has rounded corners while the original logo does not. The coordinates of the line connecting the *h* and the arc has been slightly shifted to align with the *h* diagonally. Finally the baseline of the `tikzpicture` is adjusted to align with the text.

Still some improvements can be made, and in any case it may be better to use the original logo, or to create a vector version by tracing the bitmap in, e.g., Inkscape (if you want the image to scale nicely). However, it's a nice TikZ exercise so I decided to try it anyway :)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{relsize}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\newcommand\tikzhumanitypluslogo{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={([yshift=-1.5pt]current bounding box.center)}]
        \draw[ultra thick] (-0.04,-0.25) -- (0.01,0) arc(-265:60:0.25);
        \draw (0.18,-0.21) node[] {\resizebox{3.5px}{5px}{\textbf{\textsf{-}}}};
        \draw (0.172,-0.202) node[rotate=90] {\resizebox{3.5px}{5px}{\textbf{\textsf{-}}}};
        \draw (-0.013,-0.25) node[]
            {\scalebox{1.08}{\textsf{\textbf{\textit{h}}}}};
        \draw[white,fill=white,thick] (-0.1,-0.38) -- (0.15,-0.38);
    \end{tikzpicture}}

\begin{document}
abc \tikzhumanitypluslogo\,def
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]